# How can I modify a repeater to not show data for every row bound to it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a stored proc that returns 4 rows in a table.  Each row corresponds to a day a person is staying at a hotel, so when I bind a repeater to it, 4 rows show up.  Two of the rows are the same room and the other two are the same room.  I want to display credit card information, but not for each individual room, only for every set of rooms that is the same, so it would look something like this:

12/7/2011  Room 1

12/8/2011  Room 1

Credit Card Info

12/7/2011  Room 2

12/8/2011  Room 2

Credit Card Info

I don't want to combine Room information and credit information into a one row each.  How can I get this to format the way I want it to?

Currently I am displaying Room Information in an ItemTemplate and inside the ItemTemplate is a tr and td's.

Comment: when you return your information could you just create a Dictionary<int, string[]> that will hold the information you need and use the room number as the key so for example if the Key is the same "which is the room number" skip adding the room number again and just add to the object the credit card info. Dictionary<> use the Contains() method to see if the key is in the list already or you could create a dynamic array string[] strArray= {} and load the items from the DataReader or how ever you are getting the return values or you could create a HashTable()

Comment: @DJKRAZE - I think I get what you are saying and I could do that.  Can you format your comment into an answer if possible.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
//Create either a HashTable() 
//or a Dictionary<int, string[]> I would personally use a Dictionary<> 

//create an instance of what ever collection you want to use or array
  //List<string>
  //Dictionary<int, string[]>() using the room number as the key
  // you would add the values to either the List<> or a String[] array or a Dictionary
keey in mind that if you want to create a dynamic string[] array and you do not know how many elements you are going to add just use a List<> or Dictionary<int,string>
and you can always convert that object using .ToArray 
so for example 


List<string> lstRoomList = new List<string>();
string[] arrayRoom = {};
if you have a DataReader for example and you are doing something like 
while (yourdataReader.Read())
{
  // here you can decide how you are going to work with the data you 
  lstRoomList.Add(datareader["roomnubmer"] + " " + datareader[CreditCarInfo];
}
at the end you could assign the values of that list to a dynamic array
arrayRoom = kstRoomList.ToArray(); I would really need to see what you are using and how you are returning the StoredProc results..
```

Comment: The stored proc is returning each room with the credit card info.  In code, I am returning a datatable and then binding the repeater to the datatable and binding each value from the datatable using eval.

Comment: Would another option be to just keep track of which rooms have been added and if the current room != previous room, then I add the credit info for the previous room.

Comment: you can do that using a HashTable because it has the Contains() function, you could also create your own Control break type of process.. how about pasting what you have and I will edit it with how to use a Dictionary or Hash or List it's your call.. you could even do this using a string[,] so many options

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two options:  you can pre-process the data so that what is bound to the repeater represents what you want to present to the user - DJ KRAZE has shown one way to do that.

The other option would be to add an [ItemDataBound event handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx) and manipulate the data and/or the current row at that point.

One drawback of the 2nd approach is that you need access to the prior row in order to make your decision - that may complicate things, especially if you have any paging of the results.